# Why does QGIS provide [N / A] next to the categories?

Tags: qgis, layers

What are the reasons why when I ask to show the total number of elements with a categorized stylization it shows me [N / A] next to each category?

The style is well constructed and the total number of elements for the layer works. I insert an image

Comment: Hi Luppico, if you update your post showing what the exact category/rule you are using is that may help. The feature count functionality does not always work with complex rules (e.g. one that use regexp matches)

Comment: Because they are not applicable for some reason